# image_get_intermediate_size always returns false

Tags: images

I have a question about the WordPress function `image_get_intermediate_size`. It seems to always return false for me. I've confirmed the image exists at different size - using `get_attachment_image_src`. The reason I can't use that function in this particular case, is that the image is actually bigger on smaller screens.

```
$featured_image    = get_field('square_image', $featured); // get image url
$featured_image_id = attachment_url_to_postid($featured_image); // convert url to id
$featured_image_small= image_get_intermediate_size($featured_image_id); // image thumbnail

var_dump($featured_image_small);exit();
```

In the code above, `$featured` is a post ID. The post has a few images associated with it, one of which is `square_image`, that stores an image url. `$featured_image_small` should technically retrieve the image at the thumbnail size, but it only returns false.

Comment: Can you verify that `$featured_image` is an actual image URL and `$featured_image_id` returns the correct attachment ID? If so, I would call `wp_get_attachment_metadata()` with the proper data and see if that returns false as well. If so, it could be that the image metadata was never generated for some reason.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee that was very helpful, thank you. The problem was I was trying to use the image sizes 'thumbnail' (`image_get_intermediate_size` defaults to thumbnail) and 'medium', but when I did a `var_dump` with `wp_get_attachment_metadata()`, I saw that the image sizes were actually called 'medium_large' and 'alm-thumbnail'. You can go ahead and add your answer below if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever media is uploaded, the media gets run through [`wp_generate_attachment_metadata()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_generate_attachment_metadata/). The [`image_get_intermediate_size()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/image_get_intermediate_size/) function relies on [`wp_get_attachment_metadata()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_metadata/) to ensure it has some kind of size data to work with.

If the image metadata is modified by either customizations or plugins and is missing the `thumbnail` image size, `image_get_intermediate_size()` will return false for that image size as the **default** returned size is `thumbnail`.

Comment: Just want to nit pick, because this is the correct answer but it could be clearer. The issue was that the wrong size name was used ("thumbnail" and "medium") in `image_get_intermediate_size()`. While these are usually the right image size names, sometimes they are altered by a plugin, or another developer. To see the available sizes, use `wp_get_attachment_metadata()` with the image ID.

Comment: @JillianHoenig I've updated it to hopefully clarify but feel free to submit your own edit to the answer as you're more familiar. You're also more than welcome to add your own answer - whichever provides the best information and clarity for future readers!